# Select closest date to another date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm querying a table (COURSEPLACE) to generate a result set of students. This contains a range of variables taken from the course table.

I then want to join an Addresses table (which contains multiple address records per student) but only append to the results the 1 postcode that was created on the same (or the closest) date to the date that the Student record was created.

What I've tried is the following, but this only gets me those records where the date value is an exact match - how do I extend this to (effectively) find and select the postcode value from the address record that has the closest date stamp to the student record date stamp?:

```
SELECT cp.CONTACTNO, cp.AGEONENTRY, cp.COURSETITLE, cp.FACULTY, ad.POSTCODE
FROM COURSEPLACE cp
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS ad ON ad.CONTACTNO=cp.CONTACTNO
WHERE 
cp.TYPE = 'Application'
AND cp.TERM = '2015/6'
AND 
(
ad.TYPE = 'Home' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),ad.CREATIONDATE,103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),cp.CREATIONDATE,103)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    cp.CONTACTNO, cp.AGEONENTRY, cp.COURSETITLE, cp.FACULTY, ad.POSTCODE,
FROM 
    COURSEPLACE cp
    INNER JOIN ADDRESS ad ON ad.CONTACTNO=cp.CONTACTNO
WHERE CP.TYPE = 'Application'
    AND CP.TERM = '2016/5'
    AND AD.TYPE = 'Home'
ORDER BY 
    DATEDIFF(AD.CREATIONDATE, CP.CREATIONDATE) ASC;
```

Comment: Cheers @McNets - this works as well, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with OUTER APPLY, given as an answer to a previous question:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM ADDRESS ad2 WHERE  ad2.CONTACTNO=cp.CONTACTNO ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,cp.CREATIONDATE,ad2.CREATIONDATE)) AD
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl....

```
SELECT cp.CONTACTNO, cp.AGEONENTRY, cp.COURSETITLE, cp.FACULTY, ad.POSTCODE
FROM COURSEPLACE cp
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ad ON 
    ad.CONTACTNO=cp.CONTACTNO
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT CONTACTNO, MAX(CREATIONDATE) dt 
    FROM ADDRESS
    WHERE CREATIONDATE <= cp.CREATIONDATE
    GROUP BY CONTACTNO) ad2 on ad2.dt = ad.CREATIONDATE and ad2.CONTACTNO = ad.CONTACTNO
WHERE 
cp.TYPE = 'Application'
AND cp.TERM = '2015/6'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this @scsimon, this looks to have worked as well.